# How do you display more than 3 related products in Magento 1.9?

Tags: product, related-products

Magento is only displaying 3 related products; I'm looking to display 5. What am I doing wrong/What do I need to change?

Comment: have you set more then 3 related products in admin side for particular product ?

Comment: This page ranks well for the question but the answers are not good.  You set it using the XML, here is the answer -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31449799/where-to-limit-the-related-products-in-magento

Answer (score 0):

You must be change in your themes,

```
app/design/frontend/default/your-theme/catalog/product/list/related.phtml
```

check If count mentioned 3, change it to 4,5 or the number of products you want. 
Let me know if it works

**EDIT**

Replace the

  tag which starts on line number 34, with the following code

```
<ol class="mini-products-list" id="block-related">
<?php $i=0; ?>
    <?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
    <?php if($count!=6){ ?>
        <li class="item">
            <?php if(!$_item->isComposite() && $_item->isSaleable()): ?>
                <?php if (!$_item->getRequiredOptions()): ?>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox related-checkbox" id="related-checkbox<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>" name="related_products[]" value="<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>" />
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <div class="product">
                <a href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'thumbnail')->resize(50) ?>" width="50" height="50" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>" /></a>
                <div class="product-details">
                    <p class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></a></p>
                    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item, true, '-related') ?>
                    <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo $this->getAddToWishlistUrl($_item) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Where is the count?

Comment: I ve edited my answer. Please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

- First check your package & theme name, ***Admin Panel -> System ->Config -> Design***
- Then go to your magento folder location, and edit the file `app/design/frontend/YOUR PACKAGE/YOUR THEME/template/catalog/product/list/related.phtml`
- If the file is not there, then go to `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/list/related.phtml`
- In that file, check for the count

Comment: Where is the count?